# Template Parameters of the version Type

Tags: c++, templates

So there are 3 types of template parameters:

```
type
non-type
template
```

SO if the use of templates is to serve as a "class" to classes...in other words a template is to a class what a class is to an object... and provide things such as data type independence, why would I want to use a type parameter template?
 for example, why would I ever want to use something like

```
template <int n = 1>
```

?

Thank you

Comment: Question is vague. What do you mean then?

Comment: For example for `std::array<T, N>`, `std::bitset<N>`.

Comment: I mean, what use is there for a template which takes type parameters if the whole objective of using templates is to get away from data types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, you have a relationship like:

```
(meta-template)->template->class->object
```

Meta templates are templates which can act as a kind of template generator. This is not really the truth but is also not really the truth that a template is a class generator.

Templates `can` be used as a class generator. This is what often results in multiple copies of the same code in the binary and is sometimes not what is really useful.

But a template can do much more!

Templates allow calculations during compile time. They maybe did not generate code and they will not result in any class and also not in an instance. The complete code is evaluated during compile time and results in new types which itself can be used as traits for other templates or they can calculate constants which can be used as normal values in the code. All this without any template->class->object relation.

And this is the place where sometimes integer values come in use. They can be used to do compile time calculations. And also this values can be used as traits for selecting specialization.

So simply your rule is only one facet of the c++ template world. And also in this little world, an integer can be used to create classes with this int parameters, like fixed sized arrays and others. See std::array for example where a int value for the size is a template parameter.

Another use case for int parameters in templates are recursive templates which runs over types. In this case often a counting int parameter can be used. Maybe this will be evaluated like a `switch` in compile time and the counter in compile time is something like an `enum` in the run time world.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of uses, C++ templates are not just a mean to "get away with types".

- `std::array<T, N>` is one example : capture the array size at compile time
- Many examples in the standard library : see [`std::get<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) to access `tuple` elements
- Integrals arguments can server as an input for MTP algorithms (and consequently, allow C++ templates to form a complete Turing machine, which is a major property of the language ):

[Example of a compile-time factorial :](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming)

```
template <int n>
struct factorial {
    enum { value = n * factorial<n - 1>::value };
};

template <>
struct factorial<0> {
    enum { value = 1 };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing.  You claim to ask:

> why would I want to use a type parameter template?

However your example is an example of using a non-type template parameter.

You would want/need to use a non-type template parameter (as in your example) when the value-in-question must be a compile time constant.

For example, the second template parameter of [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) affects its size, which must be a compile time constant, and therefore can only be affected by compile time constants.  Therefore you cannot specify this at run time, and therefore it must be specified via template parameter at compile time.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I had them mixed up. So then what is the fundamental differences between template parameters and function parameters?

Comment: Template parameters must be fully determined when the program is compiled.  Function parameters need not be.

Answer (score 0):

You can see an example here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/master/compiler/utils/arena_allocator.h

ArenaAllocatorStatsImpl is defined as (line 63):
template  class ArenaAllocatorStatsImpl;
where kCount means that you want to count allocations if it's true.

Then you have an implementation (line 66) of version which doesn't count allocations
template <> class ArenaAllocatorStatsImpl

In line 82 there is a generic implementation but it's used only for the case where kCount is true because false is covered by implementation in line 66.

This allows you to have two version of code. One for debugging and developing and other for production. Templates are resolved at compile time so you have no overhead on production.